# Add field at end of csv file before updating database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I update a table in my database using a .csv file. The table is for timekeeping purposes.
We have a few biometric clock systems at various locations. The biometric clock company sends me a csv file with all clock data, but the csv file does not have a field with the date.

How can I add a date to each line of the lines imported from the .csv file before writing it to the database.

(Please note that we cannot update the csv file itself, this process should happen on the php side)

Here is my current script for importing, but it does not put the $_POST['clock_date']:

```
<?php
$date = "$_POST['clock_date']";

include "connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {  
    $import="INSERT into `test`(`EmpNo`,`Name`,`Surname`,`NT`,`OT1.5`,`OT2`,`date`) values ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$date')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";

}else {

print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";
print "File name to import:<br />\n";
print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: In the question, you say `$_POST['date']`, but in the code, it says `$_POST['clock_date']`. Is this just a typo? Why have you encapsulated `$_POST['clock_date']` in a string? Have you checked that `$_POST['clock_date']` isn't empty? What datatype does the ``date`` field have? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry that's just a typo. I receive the .csv file via e-mail and in the e-mail they tell me for which date the data is. In my upload page, there is a date selector, in other words the $_POST['clock_date'] will always contain a valid date... hope this helps

Comment: You didn't answer all my questions.

Comment: The 'clock_date' field is selected on a previous page and is just carried to this one, the field will never be empty. I do not get any errors uploading the file, but I have tried a few different ideas in adding the selected date to add to each field being written to the database, but its not working. I do not know how to add /or attach the date to each line from the csv file before uploading to the database...